# WPF Drag and Drop - thumbnail when dragging

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have been Googling for thumbnails, opaque images, etc and found nothing. I think I'm just searching for the wrong thing...

I have two listboxes and you can drag from the left list to the right. The left list is composed of a bunch of user controls... what I want is while the user is dragging to show a small thumbnail/image of the user control that they are dragging. Like when you drag a file in Windows, you can see a thumbnail of the file you're dragging.

What is this called? Just the name would be great! Any links would also be appreciated, but if I know what I'm searching for I should be okay... thanks.

Comment: See *Dragged Adorner* in the [following article](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.UPKm7Wdf2Uk)

Comment: Maybe this can help in some way:

[Shell Style Drag and Drop in .NET (WPF and WinForms)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamroot/archive/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Adorner was the term I was looking for.